# Finding sub-directories on a web server

Tags: python, web-crawler

We can easily find subdirectories on our local disc using os.walk() but what if those directories are not local and are on a web server?

For example, I have a website called http://www.geoglobaldomination.org. There are a couple subdirectories that are NOT referenced on the home page. eg.http://www.geoglobaldomination.org/kml and http://www.geoglobaldomination.org/kml/temp.

How can I find those subdirectories using a simple python crawler without using the HTML tags as a reference point?

Comment: I think that even using the HTML tags that would not be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you want to access off a remote server needs to be made public in some way. There is no automatic discovery mechanism -- this is why search engines want site maps for a website.  The best practice in this case is to make a sitemap and have your crawler start there.

Answer (score 2):

**Well, in the most general sense you can't.**

There are some websites that may give you an index of subdirectories when you end your uri with a '/', or a "index.html", but they don't have to.  A website author can basically return anything they want when you visit their site (with a browser or a program).  They could return a NOT FOUND (even when the document you requests exists at the exact location you request).

It is completely implementation-dependent.